# Play song with AVPlayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

How can I play a song using AVPlayer? Here is my code.

```
    let song = filteredMusic[indexPath.row]
    let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    let isPresent = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: song, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, comparisonType: .EqualTo)
    query.addFilterPredicate(isPresent)

    let result = query.items //only going to be one song

    if result!.count == 0 {
        print("not found")
        return
    }

    let url = result![0].assetURL // for some reason this is nil

    let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url!)

    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    player.play()
```

The asset url is nil. How come?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to NKushwah for the help! I am posting my own answer for a couple reasons.

```
    let song = filteredMusic[indexPath.row]
    let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    let isPresent = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: song, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, comparisonType: .EqualTo)
    query.addFilterPredicate(isPresent)

    let result = query.collections

    if result!.count == 0 {
        print("not found")
        return
    }


    let controller = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
    let item = result![0]

    controller.setQueueWithItemCollection(item)
    controller.prepareToPlay()
    controller.play()
}
```

1. `iPodMusicPlayer` is deprecated! I used `systemMusicPlayer` instead.
2. My answer is in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Some MPMediaItelm only have their contents but not URl, So to play these you have to use MPMusicPlayerController-

```
MPMusicPlayerController *controller = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

MPMediaItem *item = result![0];

[controller setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
[controller setNowPlayingItem:item];

[controller prepareToPlay];
[controller play];
```

The applicationMusicPlayer does not support background music. Use MPMusicPlayerController's `iPodMusicPlayer` instead. It shares the state with the built-in iPod player and music will continue to play when your app enters the background.

Comment: What if I want to play the song in the background? AFAIK, that is impossible with `MPMusicPlayerController`

Comment: @user3711622 follow my edited answer. When we play song from ipod library then it doen't provide us url, and then we have to use MPMusicPlayerController.

Comment: I am going to post my own solution, with credit to you. Thanks!